# Can GADTs (or existentials) without constraints be compiled as tight as untyped ordinary ADTs?

Tags: performance, haskell, gadt, existential-type

Suppose I have some ADT, like

```
data Foo = Foo !Int
         | Bar (Int->Int) Foo
```

Now say I want to impose some kind of extra type safety, getting rid of the "magic number type":

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

newtype Intey a = Intey { getIntey :: Int }

data Foo' a where
   Foo :: !(Intey a) -> Foo' a
   Bar :: (Intey a -> Intey b) -> Foo' a -> Foo' b
```

Since `b` is just a phantom argument within the constructor, has no constraints or anything else, it is basically meaningless – except for the type checker. Can it therefore compile down to the same as `Foo`, without any performance etc. cost?

Comment: Shouldn't GADTs just compile to ADTs + equality constraints, (`~`)s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to look at the Core to be absolutely sure, but in general:

- `newtype` has no runtime cost compared to the underlying type. However something like `map getIntey` will still traverse the list doing nothing.
- Types and type parameters themselves are erased during compilation so should also have no runtime cost - this is one of the advantages of static typing. It's only if you use a type class that a runtime value might be passed around.

So in most cases you can expect the same performance, but you may need to be a little careful about operations on containers like lists.

If you restrict yourself to GHC 7.8, then the new [coerce](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/GHC-Exts.html#t:Coercible) function can help with that too.